# How to control transistor with lower base voltage than supply voltage

Tags: transistors, npn, bootstrap

Here is the link to simulation of h bridge that I built [Simulation link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l5AWAnC1b0DYRNpMB2MAZmLgFYAmMADgjMhDMYbIFMBaMMAKABcR8GaiCJEs%20MSMkNOUaGAxlqFBAUhCKkIkmHsYFStTL4q1BEdPg4IACasAZgEMArgBtefENSIUpWahgIflAgsjAKSioEFIoYRMZBetAGFEYmEWCQSJD4ZERWDHZObh42XkhY8b7UFSKaIL5FLu7cZfiIIpQCHT4MjQ7NHgDuXoF1DDWV9ZDcI5Od1WNVULMCkr3dQRszI%201bXRKVXTtrUwyHDWRYJxcG-tZ3K3MPV6NBjycB769f40%20nCwBCGsnyWXV%20wIYnx8wUEwjEwhuQmC3l8CP%20qJEyKQqSxiNWcLxIAwJiJoKCkLeIAQ5n%20F0p9NpMzKEOoEzGNOE-WKLTaknM535tO5g08OOECDG80lQQYEHY1GgPiQyEgtDIXAwOTkBhoFHw%20CQxgUGDiuQKtgGJU8JN8Ms21LGctCiuVqvVXCIWSQOo1ygNRsIFQQPiYmUKVpac1qnKpsc%20MbZcaTNyFwj21KZBI6AqBKe4qiY9OsEJBcngkAo6GraHwVh1vvLcGuuG1EHJ1KTvzINLp-KTFx7soJkiHXmsY8%20E973d7MwA5uOWDOJ1qQjN%20BUGLHxZnEeAXdB8AhCAgYrlTcYKPkkrr-e10s3ceHLTyPPxAtvaba9yF5Yrj1Pc9BEhGJQn0P19QfKgvVEOsXyaa0ACdiVJdEfxDXw5XgbgUN3dFd0wv8cLwtdY3DCUmQKOBcOJYFfzIHFf2wnCAGUrFecjMgpKiICcVwAGdWBCChuHYsdY2QLB4xCfihJE7hFy4HMxmUikUxWRcpMdClEyhFYACVqRjGFtMpfT6KYfSYDIbgjLU6kYQc8yQks9c5Fsoy2T6H4HhUdz6J9azoFskYJNpRi7SzEZMk42kKOY1ZIoYpjtJOT9jKwQjahmFDku0jK0uojdsFxbSt0yv9DyMdRGNNdQTzVDgJSVdQcUORQrloCgODAMNrEQqNsDI2kKtzBdhpYMBfAqwx124AAPYbfA1frkEYGhqXAXxWMcexWF4ABPAAdATeCQxwADsBIASzOgB7JDuHuhphH3BbHEyAhGDkdsGh%20vp4QbGYgA) in this I was somehow able to control transistors with 5 volts when supply was 9 volts
[image: h bridge]
but I still didn't completely understand it as for current to flow base voltage has to be .7v higher than emitter voltage, so I simulated only one transistor of circuit and it didn't work which means the 5 volt at base of transistor wasn't able to activate transistor [Simulation of only one transistor](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWKIAsA2ESGUwUwLRhgBQALpgEwAcIFA7BZmjvYzhPldGupClWgQVB2IlGgBmBBICcKCgjoIqMqnTQyEKcHBAATXADMAhgFcANqWIA3ED3bMmDnC9Q4ZyF9ATEA7nZRnAJYqGkg-YNpQpyiwiKEaMEcERySXYgAlVH5aFLcWPNdAzE9xHwAnGIUMFKD2OGJKlBkMauyaNvqG8mbWvITcjHYQTmgUMAo4CjA6OjgWiXEKCUCtCTpQtDo5ekTdAxMLK0qBtMoO4q7woA)

[image: only on transistor of h bridge]

So can someone please explain me how the first circuit works but second doesn't and is there a way to control transistor with lower base voltage without overcomplicating circuit with something like bootstrapping circuit

Comment: Your single-transistor simulation doesn't have a ground.

Comment: Why did you delete your old question and create a nearly identical one? Next time, you should edit your original question.

Comment: Your proposed circuit opens at >1.4v input since you have two BE junctions in series. Its no problem to controll circuit like this without bootstraping until you have PNP in high side - they opens with zeros (or exactly < Vcc-0.7) and close with Vcc (9v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work: -

[image]

Your circuit does not have a ground connection and hence there is no current return path to the 5 volt negative/neutral terminal. This means no current into the base of either transistor.